# Date difference in dd:hh:mm in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

I want to calculate the datedifference between the dates in a field and today in dd:hh:mm fromat. I have tried the following

```
Format(DateDiff("s",FieldA,Date())/86400,"dd:hh:nn")
```

But the above code doesn't give me the correct difference. For example the first value in the FieldA is 04.11.2016 11:52:56. So the difference must be around 11 days. But I get a result of 09:12:07. At what point am I going wrong?

Comment: AFAIK you cannot do that. Consider, say `DateDiff("d",FieldA,date()) & " " & Format(DateDiff("s",FieldA,now())/86400,"hh:nn")`

Comment: It works. Thanks. But why doesn't it work for dd.hh:nn format?

Comment: Because when you convert seconds, you get a number where the day is not the difference but the day returned by that number. All dates are numbers.

Comment: `Format(10, "dddd dd mmmm yyyy")` results in `Tuesday 09 January 1900` i.e. the `9` you are seeing relates to the epoch date of `1900-01-01`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function like that below. Then:

```
TimePassed: FormatYearDayHourMinuteSecondDiff(#2016/11/04 11:52:56#, Date())

'TimePassed -> 0 11 12:07:04
```

It uses an external function `Years`, but you can easily modify it to not display years.

```
Public Function FormatYearDayHourMinuteSecondDiff( _
  ByVal datTimeStart As Date, _
  ByVal datTimeEnd As Date, _
  Optional ByVal strSeparatorDate As String = " ", _
  Optional ByVal strSeparatorTime As String = ":") _
  As String

' Returns count of years, days, hours, minutes and seconds of difference
' between datTimeStart and datTimeEnd converted to
' years, days, hours and minutes and seconds as a formatted string
' with an optional choice of date and/or time separator.
'
' Should return correct output for a negative time span but
' this is not fully tested.
'
' Example:
'   datTimeStart: #2006-05-24 10:03:02#
'   datTimeEnd  : #2009-04-17 20:01:18#
'   returns     : 2 328 09:58:16
'
' 2007-11-06. Cactus Data ApS, CPH.

  Const cintSecondsHour As Integer = 60& * 60&

  Dim intYears      As Integer
  Dim intDays       As Integer
  Dim intSeconds    As Integer
  Dim intHours      As Integer
  Dim datTime       As Date
  Dim strDatePart   As String
  Dim strTimePart   As String
  Dim strYDHMS      As String

  intYears = Years(datTimeStart, datTimeEnd)
  datTimeStart = DateAdd("yyyy", intYears, datTimeStart)
  intDays = DateDiff("h", datTimeStart, datTimeEnd) \ 24
  datTimeStart = DateAdd("d", intDays, datTimeStart)
  intHours = DateDiff("h", datTimeStart, datTimeEnd)
  datTimeStart = DateAdd("h", intHours, datTimeStart)
  intSeconds = DateDiff("s", datTimeStart, datTimeEnd)

  ' Format year and day part.
  strDatePart = CStr(intYears) & strSeparatorDate & CStr(intDays)
  datTime = TimeSerial(intHours, 0, intSeconds Mod cintSecondsHour)
  ' Format hour, minute and second part.
  strTimePart = Format(datTime, "hh\" & strSeparatorTime & "nn\" & strSeparatorTime & "ss")
  strYDHMS = strDatePart & " " & IIf(datTime < 0, "-", "") & strTimePart

  FormatYearDayHourMinuteSecondDiff = strYDHMS

End Function
```

Comment: Ah, an anonymous downvoter who couldn't comprehend the code.